# Time Complexity - Overthinking operations?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

Is it possible I am completely overthinking the complexity of an operation when I should only count it as one?  This is an assignment question I have from my class.

```
Algorithm Power(n)
Pre: n :: Integer, n > 0
i = 1
while (i < n)
  print i
  i = i * 3
done
```

I am completely unsure of myself and think I am over-thinking the question

the time complexity O(N) before simplification would be O(n) = 1 + (3n + ? + 1)
The amount of times i = i*3 is done is once per loop but the variable "i" grows at an accelerating rate per iteration does this actually matter or am I over-thinking things too much?

Is it O(n) because it is just one loop or more complex than that and something along the lines of O(log n) or O(n^(1/3)) due to "i" accelerating?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My bad. Thought it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that it is not `O(n)`. A single level of loop corresponds to `O(n)` only when the loop counter (in this case `i`) increases linearly relative to `n`. As to whether it's `O(log n)` or `O(n^(1/3))`, I'll leave it to you to figure out since this is for an assignment.

Comment: Thank you, it should be easy for me to figure out as long as I know I am not over complicating things.